# Assigned a JSON to a JavaScript variable but unable to access its object values

Tags: javascript, json, soundcloud

I am assigning the soundcloud Playlists tracks to the variable "**audios**".But when i am trying to access the individual tracks objects form audios it says **undefined**.

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.3.2.js"></script>
<script>
        SC.initialize({
          client_id: 'e0daf19e8a6cb0b30ab12bf9ea4df192'
        });

        var i=348525692;
        var all_tracks=[];
        var audios =new Array();

        //invoking playlist no: 348525692
        audios = SC.get('/playlists/'+i).then(function(playlist) {
            return playlist.tracks;
        }
        );

        // Receiving the tracks of the playlist invoked
        console.log(audios);



</script>
```

Which produces below output.

[image]

and when i use audios.length or audios.id etc.  it says undefined. I want to access this data inorder to proceed ahead with my tasks. Please help.

[image]

Comment: `audios._results`?

Comment: audios._results.length?

Comment: You need to assign playlist to audios inside `then`.  A good read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 2):

You are getting  it as undefined because your value is getting logged before the array is populated with its values. The `SC.get().then()` looks like a promise based API call to me but you console log it outside the `then`. You have to use the array after the values are populated in it from your API call value assignment.

```
    <script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.3.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            SC.initialize({
            client_id: 'e0daf19e8a6cb0b30ab12bf9ea4df192'
            });

            var i=348525692;
            var all_tracks=[];
            var audios =new Array();

            //invoking playlist no: 348525692
            SC.get('/playlists/'+i).then(function(playlist) {
                    audios = playlist.tracks;
                    console.log(audios);
                    console.log(audios[0]); //individual track
                    console.log(audios.length);
                    console.log(audios[0]['id']); //individual track id, can also be written as audios[0].id
                }
            );
    </script>
```

Comment: you are absolutely correct. this way it was happening for me too. But this way i cant return the variable outside. and my purpose is to return the result outside and then use it in another function to process it.

Comment: you can use this outside as well...you can call the other function inside the `then` after `audios = playlist.tracks;`. You can pass `audios` as an argument to that function and it will be able to read the values from params and use it for processing.

Answer (score 0):

the result you get is an Object. length property is defined on arrays and string or if you do a custom definition. regarding the id property, its not defined inside the object on the first level, but its defined inside the _results array.
my guess is that you want to access the _results array and get it's length and ids.

```
audios._result.forEach(audio => {
  console.log(audio.id);
});
console.log('audios length:' + audios._result.length);
```